# How to move all files in a directory to another in hadoop

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to move all files from a directory to another directory within HDFS using spark scala. In short i need to find way to use hadoop fs -mv command in a programmatic way. As i am new to hadoop it would be great if someone could help.

Answer (score 1):

In order to perform operation on HDFS, you just need to get a [FileSystem](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) instance, via

```
val fs = FileSystem.get(sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
```

then you can use its methods to do what you want on HDFS. If you want to move a file, look at the rename `method`.

Comment: Hi mark91 I tried to use rename method but it moves the input directory to the output directory, I need to move only the files present in the input directory to output directory.

Comment: It moves the directory if you rename the directory, if you rename the files it will move the files